# The C programming language by K&R exercise 2-2: re-writing for loop avoiding && or ||

Tags: c

K&R exercise 2-2 asks us to re-write the following for loop w/out using && or ||

```
for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    s[i] = c;
```

The first thing that came to mind was simply to use some if statements. Note the code just picks up user input using getchar() and prints it out as a complete sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int main()
{
    char s[MAXLINE];
    int lim = MAXLINE;
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < lim-1;)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != '\n')
        {
            s[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        else if (c != EOF)
        {
            s[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

When I execute this it works, but I get a bunch of ?? in the terminal, I think they relate to the rest of the array size I specified (note: using array of 1000 is based on the K&R example). I thought that adding an '\0' on the else would just change the char array to match the size of the sentence. Ouptput I get is:

```
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:coding alexanderroan$ clang exercise2-2.c
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:coding alexanderroan$ ./a.out
this is a test
^D
this is a test
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:coding alexanderroan$
```

Any advice on how to adjust this?

Comment: Trigraphs......

Comment: One thing that's evident: if `c = getchar()` yields an EOF, then the body of your `if (c != '\n')` will be executed which is clearly incorrect. You should think through your `if` logic further. It's not equivalent to the original.

Comment: A hacky way to do this would be to `#include <iso646.h>` and use `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong `if()` logic

Try replacing

```
for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
  s[i] = c;
```

with

```
for(i = 0; i < lim - 1; i++) {
  c = getchar();
  if (c == EOF) {
    break;
  }
  if (c == '\n') {
    break;
  }
  s[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: Why is this CW?

Comment: Thank you, works well and is nice and succinct, seems obvious after seeing it - need more practice of thinking in if statements and loops!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work since it sets `s[i]` and increments `i` if a newline or EOF are encountered, rather than terminating,

There are all sorts of devious ways of doing it.

One way is to use the fact that zero is false in logical expressions and non-zero is true.

```
for (i = 0; i < lim - 1;  ++i)
{
    c = getchar();
    if ((c != EOF) * (c != '\n'))
       s[i] = c;
    else
       i = lim;      /*  Terminate loop since we have read EOF or '\n' */
}
```

This works since, both of the component expressions (`c != EOF` and `c != '\n'`) give a zero (false) or non-zero (true) result.   Multiplying them together only gives a true (non-zero) result if both are true (non-zero).

Note it is not possible to turn the `if` into  `if ( ((c = getchar()) != EOF) * (c != '\n'))` since the `*`  (multiplication) does not evaluate operands left to right, and doesn't do shortcutting like `&&` or `||` do.

Among other things, this exercise demonstrates that alternative approaches to using logical operators (`&&` or `||`) don't necessarily give more readable code.

Another - possibly even less readable - alternative is

```
for (i = 0; i < lim - 1;  ++i)
{
    c = getchar();
    ((c != EOF) * (c != '\n')) ? (s[i] = c) : (i = lim);
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of `*` to selectively replace `&&`.  Also could have used `&`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who's looking for a non if-statements solution --

Since the relational operator returns either 1 or 0. You can just make sure each of them returns 1. So if there are 3 conditions...

From:

```
for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    s[i] = c;
```

To:

```
for(i = 0; (i < lim - 1) + ((c = getchar()) != EOF) + (c != '\n') == 3; i++)
    s[i] = c;
```